# Pitfalls of using memory storage of index with local gateway

Tags: elasticsearch

I read http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/store.html and want to change my settings to load indexes into memory vs disk but on that page it says

"When using a local gateway (the default), file system storage with no in memory storage is required to maintain index consistency. This is required since the local gateway constructs its state from the local index state of each node."

We only have one node running right now, so I'm wondering if I can still do it to get a performance improvement. Just wanted to see if there are some real ramifications to doing this that I'm not considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will create an index with memory store and local gateway this index will disappear after the next cluster restart. I think what you are looking for is [file system store with memory caching](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/82).

Comment: Thank you for that. I wound up just using the mmapfs file system because this seems to force the filesystem to load the indexes into memory on read https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/elasticsearch/store$20memory/elasticsearch/qftwnb1p1sw/k4ge2dtkbXoJ